How to get an object into a new line with sprintf
I am working in R markdown and I used the following function with sprintf to print mean ± standard deviation [ 95% confidence interval].
my function <- function(x){
  mean_val <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  sd_val <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  ci <- qwraps2::mean_ci(x, na_rm = TRUE)
  formatted_output <- sprintf("%.1f ± %.1f [%.1f, %.1f]", mean_val, sd_val, ci[2], ci[3])
  return(formatted_output)
}

The output all comes in one line. I want to get the [95% confidence interval] in a new line below mean ± standard deviation values
I tried to add \n like that "%.1f ± %.1f \n [%.1f, %.1f]"as I read through some documents but it did not work.

I think this depends on how you are outputting it. For example, try sending your output to cat().

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?
my_function <- function(x){
  mean_val <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  sd_val <- sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  ci <- qwraps2::mean_ci(x, na_rm = TRUE)
  formatted_output <- sprintf(paste("%.1f ± %.1f", "[%.1f, %.1f]",sep = "\n\n"), mean_val, sd_val, ci[2], ci[3])
  return(cat(formatted_output))
}

my_function(x = 1:50)

25.5 ± 14.6

[21.5, 29.5]

